# Html.toHtml() is not parsing <small> tags

Tags: android, html

I'm trying to get back the text of a Button as a String, I set it previously:

```
button.setText(Html.fromHtml("<sup><small>1</small></sup>/<sub><small>8</small></sub>"));
```

but, the String returned from Html.toHtml() is:

```
<sup>1</sup>/<sub>8</sub>
```

How do I get the  tag back?

To get the string:

```
SpannedString spannedString = new SpannedString(button.getText());
Html.toHtml(spannedString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toHtml()` does not handle `<small>` tags, nor any other tags that `fromHtml()` turns into `RelativeSizeSpan` objects. You would have to write your own `Spanned`-to-HTML conveter.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.test)));
```

Define string 'test' in strings.xml

```
<string name="test"><![CDATA[<sup><small>1</small></sup>/<sub><small>8</small></sub>]]></string>
```

In your case simple put `button.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.test)));` It worked for me.